# Установка административной панели в laravel 9

Tags: laravel, orchid, административная-панель

Поставил проект ларавела 9 себе на локальный веб-сервер. Потом решил установить административную панель Orchid, следуя инструкции [документации](https://orchid.software/ru/docs/installation/). Но при установке сталкиваюсь с непреодолимыми ошибками несовместимости системы - [конфликт совместимости](http://joxi.ru/VrwgaBZTgwjR3r) смотреть [текст ошибки](http://joxi.ru/8231eaVHwgabPr).

Вопросы:

1. Как победить такую ошибку (Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.) и корректно поставить Orchid?
2. Может кто посоветует другую бесплатную (русскоязычную) административную систему для современного ларавел 9-10?
3. Успевают ли в принципе административные панели за версионным развитием laravel?

Comment: Не похоже что у вас установлена Laravel v9 так как в ошибке сказано, что у вас версия 7.29 прописана в composer.json. Думаю вам всё-таки нужно поставить версию 10, так как в composer.json у orchid/platform требование прописано как ^10.0